# How can I loop an animation and crossfading images from same src?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I have the following animation which fade in and out some images. But after the last images the animation will stop.
First, I want to loop this animation over and over again.
Second, I think is a CSS issue that the fading is not working so well as there is a pause between images when fade out and I want to know if I can overlap the images when fading.

CSS:

```
#foo {
      position:relative;
      width: 300px;
      height: 250px;
    }

    #foo img {
      left:0;
      -webkit-transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out;
      transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out;
    }

    @keyframes bannerFadeInOut {
      0% {
        opacity:0;
      }
      50% {
        opacity:1;
      }
      100% {
        opacity:0;
      }
    }

    @-moz-keyframes bannerFadeInOut {
      0% {
        opacity:0;
      }
      50% {
        opacity:1;
      }
      100% {
        opacity:0;
      }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes bannerFadeInOut {
      0% {
        opacity:0;
      }
      50% {
        opacity:1;
      }
      100% {
        opacity:0;
      }
    }

    #frames {
      position: absolute;
      animation: bannerFadeInOut;
      animation-duration: 3s;
      animation-iteration-count: 99999;
      animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    }
```

JS

```
var img, i = 1;
var nImg = 4;
div = document.getElementById('foo');
img = new Image();
    div.appendChild(img);
    img.src = 'http://tdhdemo.com/frames/frame_' + i + '.jpg';
    img.id = "frames";

var interval = setInterval(function() {
    i++;

var element = document.getElementById("frames");
element.outerHTML = "";
delete element;

    if(i > nImg) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    } else {
        img = new Image();
        div.appendChild(img);
        img.src = 'http://tdhdemo.com/frames/frame_' + i + '.jpg';
        img.id = "frames";
    }
}, 3000);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/o1zj2c1w/

Answer (score 1):

I just added a quick if statement to make a loop, it resets i back to 1 if nImg is exceeded:

```
if(i>nImg){
    i=1;
}
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o1zj2c1w/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Put the entire code into a `function` and call after you `clearInterval`

**Demo:**

```js
function init() {
    var img, i = 1;
    var nImg = 4;
    div = document.getElementById('foo');
    img = new Image();
    div.appendChild(img);
    img.src = 'http://tdhdemo.com/frames/frame_' + i + '.jpg';
    img.id = "frames";
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        i++;
        var element = document.getElementById("frames");
        element.outerHTML = "";
        delete element;
        if (i > nImg) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            init();
        } else {
            img = new Image();
            div.appendChild(img);
            img.src = 'http://tdhdemo.com/frames/frame_' + i + '.jpg';
            img.id = "frames";
        }
    }, 3000);
}
init();
```

```css
#foo {
    position:relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 250px;
}
#foo img {
    left:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes bannerFadeInOut {
    0% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    50% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:0;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes bannerFadeInOut {
    0% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    50% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:0;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes bannerFadeInOut {
    0% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    50% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:0;
    }
}
#frames {
    position: absolute;
    animation: bannerFadeInOut;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-iteration-count: 99999;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/o1zj2c1w/2/

Comment: and how can I combine the images on transition? For example if you change the speed of animation to 8 seconds then you will have like 2-3 seconds of white

Comment: The idea is not to have a background image is to crossfading as on this example but here is using multiple divs http://www.simonbattersby.com/blog/simple-jquery-image-crossfade/

Answer (score 1):

You can copy this and try again:

```
var img, i = 1;
var nImg = 4;
div = document.getElementById('foo');
img = new Image();
div.appendChild(img);
img.src = 'http://tdhdemo.com/frames/frame_' + i + '.jpg';
img.id = "frames";

var interval = setInterval(function() {
    var element = document.getElementById("frames");
    element.outerHTML = "";
    delete element;

    img = new Image();
    div.appendChild(img);
    img.src = 'http://tdhdemo.com/frames/frame_' + i + '.jpg';
    img.id = "frames";

    i = i == nImg ? 1 : i + 1;
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd just replace

```
i++;
```

with

```
i < nImg ? i++ : i = 1;
```